# How to use inner join and cross join in one query?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, cross-join

I have a task to write a query that uses a single inner join and cross join(s). The query I have already written that should return the same result looks like this :

```
SELECT T.PRICE, S.ROW, S.NUMBER, M.TITLE  
FROM 
[cinema_no_keys].[dbo].[TICKET] T cross join 
[cinema_no_keys].[dbo].[MOVIE] M cross join 
[cinema_no_keys].[dbo].[SEAT] S cross join 
[cinema_no_keys].[dbo].[SHOW] SH
WHERE
T.ID_SEAT = S.ID_SEAT AND
M.ID_MOVIE = SH.ID_MOVIE AND
SH.DATE_HOUR = T.DATE_HOUR
```

Comment: "I have a task to write a query that uses a single inner join and cross join(s)" - does this mean that you have been *told* to write a query that *must* use a single inner join and cross joins (possibly as an academic exercise), or that you need to write a query and *you* think it needs to use a single inner join and cross joins? (If the answer is the latter, see dan111's answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cross join` is a special case of `inner join`: it is an inner join without any conditions.  In other words, it joins every row of the table. The only reason it exists is so that you don't have to write a silly statement like `inner join TABLE on 1=1`.

You should *only* use cross join when you want to join every single row.  It makes no sense to use it and then have conditions in the `where` clause specifying which rows should match (as you are doing).

The proper way to do it is use `inner join`, and specify the join conditions in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause. This gives your query more of a logical flow, and in many cases it will also be more efficient (the earlier you exclude rows from your result, the faster your query runs).

Here is a revised query that uses `inner join`:

```
select T.PRICE, S.ROW, S.NUMBER, M.TITLE  
    from [cinema_no_keys].[dbo].[TICKET] T 
    inner join [cinema_no_keys].[dbo].[SEAT] S on
        T.ID_SEAT = S.ID_SEAT
    inner join [cinema_no_keys].[dbo].[SHOW] SH on
        SH.DATE_HOUR = T.DATE_HOUR
    inner join [cinema_no_keys].[dbo].[MOVIE] M on
        M.ID_MOVIE = SH.ID_MOVIE
```

I changed the order of joins: because `movie` links to a field in `show`, `show` should come before `movie`.